# Запуск несколько ассинхронных функций вместе на python

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio, асинхронность, multiprocessing

День добрый! Задача состоит в том, чтобы запустить несколько асинхронных функции разом.

Сейчас у меня только две функции: первая открывает сокет и непрерывно получает данные из этого соединения; вторая периодически делает запросы к другому серверу и отправляет в тг канал ответ на сделанный запрос и данные, которые мы получали в первой функции.

Проблема в том, что, возможно, нужно будет открывать еще сокеты и писать функции подобные второй. Можно ли выполнять асинхронные функции пареллельно? Пробовал совместить asyncio c multiprocessing и threading. Путного ничего не вышло у меня.

Вот что сейчас написал

```
import asyncio, json, time, aiohttp, websockets

async def func2(data):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url='...', json=data) as response:
            response = await response.json()
            # Обрабатываю response

async def func1():
    url = f'...'
    start_time = time.time()
    async with websockets.connect(url) as client:
        while True:
            data = json.loads(await client.recv())
            # Обрабатываю data
            if time.time() - start_time > 5*60:
                await gen_tasks()
                start_time = time.time()


async def gen_tasks():
    tasks = []
    for i in ...:
        data = {...}
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(func2(data)))
    for task in tasks:
        await task

asyncio.run(func1())
```

Comment: И в чем проблема с кодом из вопроса? С точки зрения асинхронности в нем все выглядит правильно.

Comment: Основной вопрос в том, как запускать паралельно асинхронные функции

Comment: Ну так вот же вы запустили целую кучу асинхронных функций параллельно `tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(func2(data)))`. `asyncio.create_task(f(data))` запускает f параллельно

Comment: В принципе в асинхронной функции можно собирать корутины просто в список без create_task: `tasks.append(func2(data))`, а потом запускать через `await asyncio.gather(tasks)` (если нужен результат) или `await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED)` (если результат не важен, нужно просто дождаться пока все выполнится).

Comment: Создал отдельную функцию, в которой создаются две задачи, и вызвал ее вместо func1(). Вывод, который и ожидал получить. Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Содержимое gen_tasks обернул в цикл while и в конец цикла довавил `await asyncio.sleep(300)`

В конец добавил функцию, создающую задачи

```
async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(func1())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(gen_tasks())
    await t1
    await t2

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Не забудьте отметить данный ответ как верный, чтобы закрыть этот вопрос ;)